# Perform operations while streamreader is open or copy stream locally, close the stream and then perform operations?

Tags: c#, streamreader

Which of the following approaches is better? I meant to ask, is it better to copy the stream locally, close it and do whatever operations that are needed to be done using the data? or just perform operations with the stream open? Assume that the input from the stream is huge.

First method:

```
public static int calculateSum(string filePath)
{            
    int sum = 0;
    var list = new List<int>();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                list.Add(int.Parse(sr.ReadLine()));
            }
        }

    foreach(int item in list)
        sum += item;
    return sum;
}
```

Second method:

```
public static int calculateSum(string filePath)
{            
    int sum = 0;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                sum += int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to run two loops when one is enough?

Comment: It could be written in a single line with Linq but probably the performance are not better that the single loop approach

Answer (score 0):

If the file is modified often, then read the data in and then work with it. If it is not accessed often, then you are fine to read the file one line at a time and work with each line separately.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you can do it in a single pass, then do it in a single pass. You indicate that the input is huge, so it might not all fit into memory. If that's the case, then your first option isn't even possible.

Of course, there are exceptions to every rule of thumb. But you don't indicate that there's anything special about the file or the access pattern (other processes wanting to access it, for example) that prevents you from keeping it open longer than absolutely necessary to copy the data.

I don't know if your example is a real-world scenario or if you're just using the sum thing as a placeholder for more complex processing. In any case, if you're processing a file line-by-line, you can save yourself a lot of trouble by using [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
{
    sum += int.Parse(line);
}
```

This does not read the entire file into memory at once. Rather, it uses an enumerator to present one line at a time, and only reads as much as it must to maintain a relatively small (probably four kilobyte) buffer.